# What comes out of this bump in this vegetable?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, species-identification

I live in Denmark, Europe and I have in my garden this gigantic vegetable.

It has a big bump on the top and i was wondering about what comes out of it?

[image]

Comment: Where is the plant located?

Comment: I just edited my question and put in it's location which is Denmark, Europe.

Comment: @WYSIWYG. I accidentally used the danish word for the vegetable. I do not know the english name for it so i just changed it to vegetable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your vegetable is a leek, or a closely related allium. If this is the case, you are seeing its flowerbud. Congratulations, it will become quite pretty in some days, I know people who use leeks as decoration plants instead of vegetables.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for enlightening me. Im carefully following the process of this plant. Nature is amazing!

Comment: @Lanka did you ever get a photo of the plant in flower? It would be neat to see that added as an update to your question.

Comment: Hi:) I never got another pic from it and now I moved to Greenland so I dont have the garden anymore. Hopefully Ill get one when I move back to Denmark again. Thanks for asking btw.